# how to check for condition on each page after a user has logged in in django

Tags: django, django-views

I have a condition, whether a user has setup some account information or not.  If a user does not meet this condition, I want to throw a popup on the screen.

How can I accomplish this in the most resource efficient way, so as to not have to query the database for every view a user hits.  Or is this not a problem because it is optimized through django?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a context processor for my specific case, but for checking a condition, I believe custom middleware is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Look into implementing a decorator for the view you are interested in restricting access to - Django provides some [decorators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#limiting-access-to-logged-in-users-that-pass-a-test) that are useful.  If you do not find one that fits your needs perfectly, consider writing a custom one.

Edit: To reduce the number of database hits, you should save the results in the cache/session.